# Why my application is crushing when i use openCv Mat

Tags: android, image, opencv

I am  new in openCV android image Processing. but i am facing some problem. when i use openCV in android and i use Mat then my apps will crushed.... what is the problem with this.....

**My code is here..:**

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    ImageView img=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.in);

    Mat tmp = new Mat (b.getWidth(), b.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
    Utils.bitmapToMat(b, tmp);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(tmp, tmp, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
      //there could be some processing
    Imgproc.cvtColor(tmp, tmp, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGB, 4);
    Utils.matToBitmap(tmp, b);
    img.setImageBitmap(b);

}
```

Comment: Try to comment out some code lines to provide a minimal code example. Which line is causing the crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems:

1. Mat constructor is `Mat(height, width, type)`, you inverted height and width.
2. `CV_8UC1` is a single channel (grayscale). So if it IS necessary to create the Mat in advance, you should create a Mat with appropriate number of channels. I assume you want to use a RGB image, so use `CV_8UC3`. But typically, functions re-allocate the Mat if the size doesn't fit. If that's the case with `bitmapToMat` too, then there is another problem.
3. Afaik, android uses RGBA as standard color-space. So PROBABLY after `Utils.bitmapToMat(b, tmp);` tmp is a 4 channel RGBA matrix. So please try `Imgproc.cvtColor(tmp, tmp, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);` and later `Imgproc.cvtColor(tmp, tmp, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA, 4);` if you aren't sure you should add some checks like `if Mat.channels isn't 3, don't try to convert RGB2GRAY` if the check fails you can try to find out what the real number of channels is and why.